# GestureDetector onScaleUpdate resets to 0

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a following code that basically rotates/resizes using pinch gesture detector. But for some reason, `scale` and `angle` resets to 0 when scale ends.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'dart:math' as math;

void main() {
  debugPaintSizeEnabled = true;
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: PinchRotateZoom(),
    );
  }
}

class PinchRotateZoom extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PinchRotateZoomState createState() => _PinchRotateZoomState();
}

class _PinchRotateZoomState extends State<PinchRotateZoom> {
  double _width = 300;
  double _height = 200;

  Matrix4 _matrix = Matrix4(
    1, 0, 0, 0, //
    0, 1, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 1, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 1,
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Transform(
          transform: _matrix,
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: GestureDetector(
            onScaleUpdate: (details) {
              var angle = details.rotation;
              var scale = details.scale;

              print(angle);
              print(scale);

              var angleMatrix = Matrix4.identity();
              angleMatrix[0] = angleMatrix[5] = math.cos(angle);
              angleMatrix[1] = math.sin(angle);
              angleMatrix[4] = -math.sin(angle);

              var scaleMatrix = Matrix4.identity();
              scaleMatrix[0] = scaleMatrix[5] = scale;

              _matrix = angleMatrix * scaleMatrix;
              setState(() {});
            },
            child: Container(
              height: _height,
              width: _width,
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: *"But for some reason, scale and angle resets to 0 when scale ends."* - yes, this is how it works by design - its not a bug

Comment: Is there a way to disable this behavior? @pskink

Comment: no, you cannot do that - you need to add / multiply the values of `angle` and `scale` im your code

Comment: your welcome, see [matrix_gesture_detector.dart](https://github.com/pskink/matrix_gesture_detector/blob/master/lib/matrix_gesture_detector.dart), and check `rotationUpdater` and `scaleUpdater`

Comment: I did the calculations manually. I think it works well. @pskink

Comment: with the code i posted you can do the same by using: `MatrixGestureDetector(
onMatrixUpdate: (m, tm, sm, rm) {
notifier.value = m;
},
child: AnimatedBuilder(
animation: notifier,
builder: (ctx, child) {
return Transform(
transform: notifier.value, child: ...` - where `notifier` is `ValueNotifier<Matrix4>` - full example [here](https://github.com/pskink/matrix_gesture_detector/blob/master/example/lib/transform_demo.dart)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved it this way:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'dart:math' as math;

void main() {
  debugPaintSizeEnabled = true;
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      // home: EditorScreen(),
      home: PinchRotateZoom(),
    );
  }
}

class PinchRotateZoom extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PinchRotateZoomState createState() => _PinchRotateZoomState();
}

class _PinchRotateZoomState extends State<PinchRotateZoom> {
  double _width = 300;
  double _height = 200;

  Matrix4 _matrix = Matrix4(
    1, 0, 0, 0, //
    0, 1, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 1, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 1,
  );

  double _baseScaleFactor = 1.0;
  double _scaleFactor = 1.0;

  double _baseAngleFactor = 0;
  double _angleFactor = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Transform(
          transform: _matrix,
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: GestureDetector(
            onScaleStart: (details) {
              _baseScaleFactor = _scaleFactor;
              _baseAngleFactor = _angleFactor;
            },
            onScaleUpdate: (details) {
              _scaleFactor = _baseScaleFactor * details.scale;
              _angleFactor = _baseAngleFactor + details.rotation;

              var angleMatrix = Matrix4.identity();
              angleMatrix[0] = angleMatrix[5] = math.cos(_angleFactor);
              angleMatrix[1] = math.sin(_angleFactor);
              angleMatrix[4] = -math.sin(_angleFactor);

              var scaleMatrix = Matrix4.identity();
              scaleMatrix[0] = scaleMatrix[5] = _scaleFactor;

              _matrix = angleMatrix * scaleMatrix;
              setState(() {});
            },
            child: Container(
              height: _height,
              width: _width,
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```